# I want to show a image moving from right top corner to left bottom corner in simple html

Tags: javascript, html

onmouseover() I am calling this function

```
function move_arrow() {

        document.getElementById('arrow1').style.display = "block";
        j = 100;
        for (var i = 1000; i > 260; i--) {
            document.getElementById('arrow1').style.left = i + 'px';
            document.getElementById('arrow1').style.top = j + 'px';
            if (j < 440) {
                j = j + .5;
            }
         //alert();      

        }
    }
```

With alert its shows image moving to desired position otherwise its not. I know with alert it gets sufficient time to execute the function. 
What can be the right solution for this in simple html and javascript which works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You may use setInterval for example:

```
function move_arrow() {
    document.getElementById('arrow1').style.display = "block";
    j = 100;
    i = 1000;
    var intervalId = setInterval(
        function() {
            i--;
            document.getElementById('arrow1').style.left = i + 'px';
            document.getElementById('arrow1').style.top = j + 'px';
            if (j < 440) {
                j = j + .5;
            }

            if (i < 240)
                clearInterval(intervalId); //switch off setInterval
        }, 
        10 //execute this function every 10ms
    );
}
```